# SQL Query to Calculate Monthly Budget

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
(
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Budget_Day] [MONEY] NULL,
    [DateCreated] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [DateDeleted] [DATETIME] NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget] ([Name], [Budget_Day], [DateCreated], [DateDeleted]) 
VALUES (N'SAM', 20.0000, CAST(N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-10-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (N'ROB', 10.0000, CAST(N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL),
       (N'TAM', 5.0000, CAST(N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (N'TAN', 100.0000, CAST(N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL)
```

The above is the table structure we had to calculate monthly budget.

We are displaying the bar graph for each name how their monthly budget is.
Suppose if we take Sam his budget for Jan is 620 and Feb is 580 and so on, So we need to calculate the budget for each month until `DateDeleted` has value

We are able to calculate the budget per month for each Employee Name, but unable 
to figure out how to calculate them for consecutive months.

Please, anyone, help me on this
How to write SQL for the above approach.
Please sample  table data

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT A.Name,A.budget_day,B.MonthName,B.totaldays*A.budget_day as MonthlySpent
FROM 
[dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget] A
inner join(
SELECT [Name] , DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1) AS MonthName,DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1)) as totaldays,month(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1)) as monthOrder
from [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
inner join    (SELECT 1 monthnos UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) nos on  nos.monthnos <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, [DateCreated],isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE()))+1
 ) B on
A.NAME=B.Name 
order by A.Name,monthOrder
```

Try This

```
       select name,budget_day,monthname,totalspent from
(Select j.* ,row_number () over (partition by j.name,j.monthname order by j.totalspent) as rn

from

(Select B.name,A.budget_day,MonthName,(datediff(day,[DateCreated],DefaultDate)+1)*A.budget_day as TotalSpent,monthOrder
from (SELECT 
  *, [Budget_Day]*DATEDIFF(day,[DateCreated],isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE())) as TotalSpent,  DATENAME(MONTH, [DateCreated]) AS MonthNameStart, DATENAME(MONTH,isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE())) AS MonthNameEND
from 
   [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
 where datecreated<=isnull(datedeleted,getdate())) A
LEFT join 


(
SELECT [Name] , DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos-1, [DateCreated])) AS MonthName,EOMONTH([DateCreated]) as DefaultDate ,
DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1)) as totaldays,
month(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos-1, [DateCreated])) as monthOrder
from [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
inner join    (SELECT 1 monthnos UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) nos on  nos.monthnos <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, [DateCreated],isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE()))

)  B
on A.MonthNameStart =B.MonthName and 
A.Name=B.name

UNION

Select B.name,A.budget_day,MonthName,((datediff(day,DefaultDate,isnull([Datedeleted],getdate())))+1)*A.budget_day as TotalSpent,monthOrder from
(SELECT 
  *, [Budget_Day]*DATEDIFF(day,[DateCreated],isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE())) as TotalSpent,  DATENAME(MONTH, [DateCreated]) AS MonthNameStart, DATENAME(MONTH,isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE())) AS MonthNameEND
from 
   [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
   where datecreated<=isnull(datedeleted,getdate())) A
   inner join 


(SELECT [Name] , DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1) AS MonthName,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, isnull([DateDeleted],getdate())), 0) as DefaultDate,
DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1)) as totaldays,
month(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos, [DateCreated])-1)) as monthOrder
from [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
inner join    (SELECT 1 monthnos UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) nos on  nos.monthnos <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, [DateCreated],isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE()))+1)  B
on A.MonthNameEND =B.MonthName and A.Name=B.name

UNION


SELECT B.name,A.budget_day,MonthName,totaldays*A.budget_day as TotalSpent ,monthOrder
FROM 
[dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget] A
inner join(
SELECT [Name] , DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos-1, [DateCreated])) AS MonthName,EOMONTH([DateCreated]) as DefaultDate ,
DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos-1, [DateCreated]))) as totaldays,
month(DATEADD(MONTH, nos.monthnos-1, [DateCreated])) as monthOrder
from [dbo].[EmployeeMonthlyBudget]
inner join    (SELECT 1 monthnos UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) nos on  nos.monthnos <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, [DateCreated],isnull([DateDeleted],GETDATE()))
 where datecreated<=isnull(datedeleted,getdate())
) B on
A.NAME=B.Name


 )j)k
where k.rn=1 and k.name is not null
order by k.name,k.monthOrder
```

Comment: Instead of getting total at once, can we break down result into monthly

Comment: Thanks Ajan, But need to calculate values for each month instead of calculating for all month Need How much budget is spent by monthly basis

Comment: sure but need to add an extra column for month in your table

Comment: Could you please guide

Comment: Also i created a fiddle for testing https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74aad5ae86ee0b39dc4c982ef7b169f9

Comment: I have did the changes just try this

Comment: Were you able to look into this

Comment: Ajan, It worked but had one problem, if the DateCreated is "2018-01-15"  middle of the month or other days, it is calculating for the entire month from beginning date instead of taking date from 15 and it is also skipping January 16 days calucation Please look into the fiddle below i updated https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9cf6c00c774214056bd8cdd250b8e105

Comment: I know it's a painful code but this would do, This code can be more optimized

Comment: Thanks, Ajan,https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6234bda1d44d2b4e98a998435bb3d65  Evert thing looks good. Apart from the starting month. Please look at the result below [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6234bda1d44d2b4e98a998435bb3d65)

Comment: BMMV You mean the ending month is properly calculated but starting month is not ?

Comment: Ajan, Everything looks except for the Month of February, it takes 31 days * budget and remaining all months data looks good

Comment: When I checked now it didn't, can you generate the answer for that and share the link so that I can check

Comment: Can you check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ace62b2ec83415c4f2c44178bcb2c0be

Comment: Can you try the code now, I handled such scenario in code

Comment: Ajan, Please check the below link for that scenario only for the first person (Bob record)the problem with February arises remaining all looks good https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01e3e4298b3e78b024a17586044a5074

Comment: Just checked, SAM and TAM records populating, but the users with DateDeleted null is not populating in the results

Comment: yes i changed that part a lil while ago, now all good I think can you copy the code which is there now, cheers

Comment: Ajan, Little confused about the updated SQL code, do you mean in the fiddle? or above in this post

Comment: I mean in the post